# Objective-c: Most efficient way to get the shortest range from a collection (NSArray) with ranges

Tags: ios, objective-c, algorithm, nsarray, nspredicate

I have an `NSArray` that contains multiple objects which in itself have date ranges `NSDate *start` and `NSDate *end`.

What I want to do is to iterate through this array to find the shortest range (between `Start` and `End`), based on the current `date`. Something like this:

```
Date range Start 1 >----------< Date range End 1
    Date range Start 2 >-< Date range End 2
                        |
                   Current date
```

In the example above I would like to get the object that contains `Date range start 2` and `Date range End 2`.

Any ideas and suggestions on how to achieve this?

**Update**

With based on current date I mean that the current date should be somewhere inside the range. I don't want a range that has an end date that is before the current date, nor a range that has a start date that is in the future.

Comment: You mean to extract the current date in array??

Comment: Can you clarify how the current date is included in the calculation?  `based on` is not specific enough.

Comment: And if multiple ranges match you want the shortest?

Comment: @AlexBrown Hmm, good question. Do you think that's possible if I use NSDate timestamps?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple options, depending on how in depth you want the results to be.  The first (and easiest) way would be to sort the array by smallest date range:

```
array = array1 sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id obj1, id obj2) {
    double a = [obj1.endDate timeIntervalSinceDate:obj1.startDate];
    double b = [obj2.endDate timeIntervalSinceDate:obj2.startDate];

    if ( a < b ) {
        return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedAscending;
    } else if ( a > b ) {
        return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedDescending;
    } else {
        return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedSame;
    }
}
```

Then when you need to check for the shortest one containing today's date you can just start at the beginning of the array and check if the startdate is before now and the enddate is after now.  The first object that matches that criteria is your smallest range around today.

```
NSDate *date = [NSDate date];
Object *foundObject;
for(Object *obj in array)
{
    if([obj.startDate timeIntervalSinceDate:date] <= 0 && [obj.endDate timeIntervalSinceDate:date] >= 0)
    {
        foundObject = obj;
        break;
    }
}
```

If you want to go more in depth you can use a predicate to get a filtered array of all objects that surround today's date.  then you can get the shortest range and every other range that includes the date you are looking for.

```
NSPredicate *pred = [NSPredicate predicateWithBlock:^BOOL(id evaluatedObject, NSDictionary *bindings) {
    if([evaluatedObject.startDate timeIntervalSinceDate:date] <= 0 && [evaluatedObject.endDate timeIntervalSinceDate:date] >= 0)
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}];
NSArray *array = [array1 filteredArrayUsingPredicate:pred];
```

Comment: It would almost certainly be faster to first filter the array of objects to only those that contain today's date (using your predicate), then sort the resulting filtered array by the start-to-end range of dates (as you show in your sortedArrayUsingComparator code). Sorting is time-consuming, much faster for shorter arrays. For large arrays of these objects it would be faster to add a range value to each object (as an NSTimeInterval) rather than calculating it each time, since sorting involves multiple comparisons. However, for fairly small arrays the differences would be tiny.

Comment: @Duncan C True, but I was under the impression that the array would be sorted once and then multiple calls to check for date ranges would be made.  If it's a one off kind of deal you are absolutely right.

Comment: filtering would be o(N) I guess ..  hard to beat with average sorting ;)

Comment: @Duncan C Thank you, sir.  And thank's for your clarification as well.

Answer (score 2):

I think, this should be a good start point, but I can't provide working code since there is no clear definition, so:

```
// Result with minimum range
// Assuming that DateRangeObject has start and end properties of NSDate
DateRangeObject *result = nil;
// Array containing DateRangeObject objects
NSArray *arr /* = TODO: provide the content for an array */;
if (arr.count) { /* only if the array contains something */
    // Initial result
    result = arr[0];
    double minTS = DBL_MAX; // max double value, not zero ;) lol
    for (DateRangeObject *dro in arr) {
        // Get the timestamps for start and end;
        double tss = [dro.start timeIntervalSince1970];
        double tse = [dro.end timeIntervalSince1970];
        // Difference between end and start (positive value)
        double diff = tse - tsa;
        if (minTS < diff) {
            minTS = diff;
            // Current minimum
            result = dro;
        }
    }
}
```